# read line from file but store as list (python)

Tags: python

i want to read a specific line in a textfile and store the elements in a list.

My textfile looks like this

```
'item1' 'item2' 'item3'
```

I always end up with a list with every letter as an element

what I tried

```
line = file.readline()
        for u in line:
            #do something
```

Comment: Can you show the code snippet that resulted in your error/issue?

Comment: Try `for u in line.split():` Also you may need to `.strip()` the `'` from `u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
for u in line.split():
```

Which assumes there are whitespaces between each item. Otherwise you'll simply iterate over a `str` and thus iterate character by character.

You might also want to do:

```
u = u.strip('\'')
```

to get rid of the `'`

Answer (score 3):

```
line = file.readline()
for u in line.split():
    # do stuff
```

This assumes the items are split by whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

split the line by spaces and then add them to the list:

```
# line = ('item1' 'item2' 'item3') example of line
listed = []
line = file.readline()
for u in line.split(' '):
    listed.append(u)

for e in listed:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have there will read one whole line in, and then loop through each character that was in that line. What you probably want to do is split that line into your 3 items. Provided they are separated by a space, you could do this:

```
line = file.readline()      # Read the line in as before
singles = line.split(' ')   # Split the line wherever there are spaces found. You can choose any character though
for item in singles:        # Loop through all items, in your example there will be 3
    #Do something
```

You can reduce the number of lines (and variables) here by stringing the various functions used together, but I left them separate for ease of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `with`, `re` and basically take anything between apostrophes... (this'll work for strings that have spaces inside them (eg: `item 1` `item 2`, but obviously nested or string escape sequences won't be caught).

```
import re

with open('somefile') as fin:
    print re.findall("'(.*?)'", next(fin))
    # ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the characters of the line in a list you could try this.

This use double list comprehension.

```
with open('stackoverflow.txt', 'r') as file:
    charlist = [c for word in file.readline().split(' ') for c in word ]
    print(charlist)
```

If you want to get rid off some char, you can apply some filter for example; I don't want the char = ' in my list.

```
with open('stackoverflow.txt', 'r') as file:
    charlist = [c for word in file.readline().split(' ') for c in word if(c != "'")]
    print(charlist)
```

If this double list comprehension looks strange is the same of this.

```
with open('stackoverflow.txt', 'r') as file:
    charlist = []
    line = file.readline()
    for word in line.split(' '):
        for c in word:
            if(c != "'"):
                charlist.append(c)

    print(charlist)
```